# Running background tasks in ios

Tags: ios

In Android you can run background services - for example play music while app is not active or even running. Will startup automatically when the phone starts up.

What's the equivalent for ios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are background modes in Swift that you can learn about [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/configuring-background-execution-modes).

Here is the gist:

| Mode | Description | Platforms |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Audio, AirPlay, and Picture in Picture | The app plays audible content in the background. For more information, see Configuring your app for media playback. | iOS, iPadOS, tvOS |
| Audio | The app plays audible content in the background. For more information, see Playing Background Audio. | watchOS |
| Location updates | The app provides location-based information and requires the use of the platform’s standard location service. For more information, see Configuring your app to use location services. | iOS, iPadOS, watchOS |
| Voice over IP | The app provides Voice over IP services and requires automatic launch after system restart. For more information, see the CallKit framework. | iOS, iPadOS |
| External accessory communication | The app communicates with an accessory that delivers data at regular intervals. For more information, see the External Accessory framework. | iOS, iPadOS, tvOS |
| Uses Bluetooth LE accessories | The app communicates with a Bluetooth accessory while in the background. For more information, see the Core Bluetooth framework. | iOS, iPadOS |
| Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory | The app uses peripheral mode to communicate with a Bluetooth accessory. For more information, see the Core Bluetooth framework. | iOS, iPadOS |
| Background fetch | The app requires new content from the network at regular intervals. For more information, see Using background tasks to update your app. | iOS, iPadOS tvOS |
| Remote notifications | The app uses push notifications as a signal that new content is available to download. For more information, see Pushing background updates to your App. | iOS, iPadOS, watchOS, tvOS |
| Background processing | The app executes scheduled tasks while in the background. For more information, see BGTaskScheduler. | iOS, iPadOS, tvOS |
| Workout processing | The app uses a workout session to track a user’s activity on Apple Watch. For more information, see Running workout sessions. | watchOS |
| Uses Nearby Interaction | The app locates and interacts with nearby devices. For more information, see the Nearby Interaction framework. | iOS, iPadOS, watchOS |
| Push to Talk | The app launches in response to a push notification and plays audible content in the background. For more information, see the Push to Talk framework. | iOS, iPadOS |